# How to change the path of views content?

Tags: entities, views

have developed a website for my team and used VIEWS for all the link in the website.

While trying to click the links from client system it shows some error that says remote connection doesn't accept it.. like localhost some problem.. i don know how to resolve it..

I use to paste the IP address of the server and open in client system, so while doing like that in client system it will show this **"http://localhost:8082/"** . So i think the client system takes the local host so can anybody have an idea to resolve it.

The remote device or resource won't accept the connection.
after troublshooting the result is this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you have used absolute url(starting from *http://localhost:8082/content/..*) instead of relative url(starting directly from *content/..*)

Comment: Thank you Ajit i found the problem, instead of pasting the IP address of the server, simply i left as local host in menu address field.. Now it is working perfectly.

Comment: thats all right.. sometimes we tend to forget basics while doing complex things ;)